# How to find smallest value(from values given in a txt file) using BufferedReader in java

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

I have been given this question for practice and am kind of stuck on how to complete it. It basically asks us to create a program which uses a BufferedReader object to read values(55, 96, 88, 32)  given in a txt file (say "s.txt") and then return the smallest value of the given values.
    So far I have got two parts of the program but i'm not sure how to join them together.

```
import java.io.*;

class CalculateMin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("grades.txt"));
            int numberOfLines = 5;

            String[] textInfo = new String[numberOfLines];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
                textInfo[i] = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException ie) {
        }

    }
}
```

and then I have the loop which I made but i'm not sure how to implement it into the program above. Eugh I know i'm complicating things.

```
int[] numArray;
numArray = new int[Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())];
int smallestSoFar = numArray[0];
for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
    if (numArray[i] < smallestSoFar) {
        smallestSoFar = numArray[i];
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find max value in java from file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885188/find-max-value-in-java-from-file-input)

Comment: Almost but we were specified to use BufferedReader rather than Scanner  class. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it iterates through the entire file comparing number from each line with the previously read lowest number-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("grades.txt"));
        String line;
        int lowestNumber = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int number;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                number = Integer.parseInt(line);
                lowestNumber = number < lowestNumber ? number : lowestNumber;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                // print the error saying that the line does not contain a number
            }
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("Lowest number is " + lowestNumber);
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        // print the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi appreciate the immediate reply, just got a question regarding this line: lowestNumber = number < lowestNumber ? number : lowestNumber;
Can you explain what this line means? Thanks

Comment: Initially, the lowestNumber is holding the max integer value. Now as it starts reading the file, it checks if the read number is lower than the previous stored number. First time, it will certainly be true. Thereafter, if the next number read from the file is smaller than the previously stored number, it will replace that number.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense :) One last question. I'm new to the "?" in the program you have provided. What role does it play? Thanks

Comment: Its a conditional operator (?:), which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement. This operator is also known as the ternary operator because it uses three operands. This operator should be read as: "If someCondition is true, assign the value of value1 to result. Otherwise, assign the value of value2 to result."