# How do I find the largest number and the smallest number from the user input? (while loop)

Tags: java, while-loop, max, min

Not sure where to begin honestly, I was able to find average using the user's input but can't seem to figure out the largest number or the smallest number from the numbers entered. Is there a method I can use? Any help would be great. Thank you.

EDIT: Somewhat figured it out. However the answers always seem to be largest number = 2.1478... or Smallest number = -2.1478...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("Enter the number of grades: ");
double random = input.nextDouble();
double min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
double max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

double total=0;
int count = 1;
while (count < random+1) {




    System.out.println("Enter grade " + count + ":");

    double somenumber = input.nextDouble();
    total+=somenumber;

    count++;

    if (somenumber > max){
        max = somenumber;
    }
if (somenumber < min){
    min = somenumber;
}


}
System.out.println("Total is " + total);
System.out.println("Average is " + (total/random));
System.out.println("Largest number is " + max);
System.out.println("Smallest number is" + min);



        }
```

}

Comment: Just have 2 variables for min and max and keep track of those everytime you get an input number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find max value in java from file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885188/find-max-value-in-java-from-file-input)

Comment: Would those variables be outside the loop?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Above while loop...

```
double max = 0;
double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
```

In loop after you set some number...

```
if (someNumber > max){
  max = someNumber;
}
if (someNumber < min){
  min = someNumber;
}
```

Np glad it helped :) you should consider using a for loop instead of a while loop and declare someNumber outside of the loop like so:

```
double someNumber;
for (int i = 1; i <= random; i++){
  //...
}
```

To make it even cleaner you could replace i <= random in the for loop with

```
i <= readNumGrades(input);
private double  readNumGrades(Scanner in){
  System.out.println("Enter the number of grades");
  return in.nextDouble();
}
```

So you no longer need the variables count and random

Comment: This reallllllllllllllllllllllly helped. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should at least initialize `min` and `max`, otherwise your code won't even compile...

Comment: If every number is positive which im assuming will/should be (he just hasn't been bothered to handle those cases then it shouldn't matter)

Comment: That is not correct - if every number is positive, then `min` will always be 0 in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want some code that looks like

```
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double max = 0.00;  // assume use positive numbers

while (count < random+1) {

System.out.println("Enter grade " + count + ":");

double somenumber = input.nextDouble();
total+=somenumber;

count++;

max = Math.max (somenumber, max);
min = Math.min (somenumber, min);

}
```

Comment: You should use `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. This will work with any input - your code already fails if the input is 0

Comment: @MartinS Good point about if input is zero.  I not think that grades should be negative, so a starting of max = `0.00;` is fine.

Comment: @MartinS MAX_VALUE = A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double - Should be big enough for a Grade.

Comment: True but when using negative infinity as i suggested it looks nicer when the other one is positive infinity ^^ But yea max value is totally fine

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Updated to use `Double` instead and now uses your original loop condition.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double smallest = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; //Initialize to largest int possible
        double largest = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY; //Initialize to smallest int possible
        System.out.println("Enter the number of grades: ");
        double random = input.nextDouble();
        int count = 1;

        while (count < random + 1) {
            System.out.print("Input Number: ");
            Double x = input.nextDouble();
            if (x < smallest) {
                smallest = x;
            }
            if (x > largest) {
                largest = x;
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Smallest: " + smallest + ", Largest: " + largest);
    }
}
```

Sample run:

> run: 
>   Enter the number of grades: 
>   5
>   Input Number: 2.5454
>   Input Number: 3.454
>   Input Number: -100.54
>   Input Number: 5687
>   Input Number: 579873.5654
>   Smallest: -100.54, Largest: 579873.5654
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I found a different route, but thank you nonetheless for stirring me in the right direction.

Comment: @Coco what route was that? Judging from other answers/comments it's the exact same logic. Except I gave you pretty much all you needed lol. Anyways, cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for the tips everyone. However, when I ran my program. I wasn't able to get the proper answers for the max and min value.

EDIT: SOLVED. THANK YOU ALL WHO CONTRIBUTED. <33

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("Enter the number of grades: ");
double random = input.nextDouble();
double min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
double max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

double total=0;
int count = 1;
while (count < random+1) {




    System.out.println("Enter grade " + count + ":");

    double somenumber = input.nextDouble();
    total+=somenumber;

    count++;

    if (somenumber > max){
        max = somenumber;
    }
if (somenumber < min){
    min = somenumber;
}


}
System.out.println("Total is " + total);
System.out.println("Average is " + (total/random));
System.out.println("Largest number is " + max);
System.out.println("Smallest number is" + min);



        }
```

}

Largest number is 2.14748 Smallest number is -2.147478...That's what was printed...Am I making a arthimetic error?

Comment: You mixed up the initializations for min and max

Comment: I'm sorry but I thought it was correct. min = Integer.MIN_VALUE; and max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Sorry if I sound like I have really basic knowledge when it comes to java because I do >_>

Comment: No worries, this happens to me too ^^

Comment: have you tried this?
`double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;`
`double max = 0.0;` (assuming the values will never be smaller than 0)

Comment: OMG I GOT IT OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG

Comment: You were right I think? ^^ I set up the if statements incorrectly.

new if statements

if (max > somenumber){
   max = somenumber;
  }
 if (min < somenumber){
  min = somenumber;
 }